# How to configure synchronous SQLAlchemy ORM use in an ASGI app?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, asgi

I am attempting to configure an ASGI application whose data layer relies on SQLAlchemy ORM. I know that it's possible to use Core completely asynchronously with something like [databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/) or [GINO](https://python-gino.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). However, our server architecture is such that database roundtrips are typically quite short (I am looking to use ASGI to improve CPU usage for IOT communication round-trips, which are several orders of magnitude greater than the time it takes to hit the database), so I'd rather just use SQLAlchemy synchronously within an otherwise async context.

Does anyone know of any prior art for setting up an ASGI server that relies on SQLAlchemy ORM for data persistence? In particular, I am wondering if there are any gotchas for session handling, how database I/O is likely to interact with request handling, etc. and have not had much luck finding this sort of knowledge online.